# How do I return a subquery more than 1 rows using having?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that can return the intended value but only 1 row. I need to have at least 26 rows of the values due based on the having clause.

| Town | floor_area_sqm | resale_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| toronto | 30 | 4500 |
| chicago | 44 | 300 |
| toronto | 22 | 3000 |
| sydney | 54 | 3098 |
| pittsburg | 102 | 2000 |
| sydney | 101 | 2000 |
| pittsburg | 129 | 2000 |

```
SELECT town, floor_area_sqm, resale_price
FROM X.flat_prices as X
GROUP BY town
HAVING Min(floor_area_sqm) = (SELECT MIN(floor_area_sqm) FROM X.flat_prices HAVING MAX(resale_price));
```

By using the formula above I get this:

| Town | floor_area_sqm | resale_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chicago | 44 | 300 |

So the answer should show something like the following:

| Town | floor_area_sqm | resale_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chicago | 44 | 300 |
| toronto | 22 | 3000 |
| sydney | 54 | 3098 |
| pittsburg | 102 | 2000 |

It should pull the lowest sqm for the town with the highest resale value. I got 26 towns and a database of over 200k.

I would like to replicate with MAX sqm using the same formula. Is join the way/only way to do it?

Comment: What is `HAVING MAX(resale_price)` supposed to do? You need to compare the max with something. Without a comparison, it's equivalent to `HAVING MAX(resale_price) != 0`

Comment: I don't understand your expected result. The highest resale value in toronto is 4500. Why does the result have 3000?

Comment: So I want to find the lowest sqm but highest resale value in each town. So a town can have 30 same sqm but different resale values @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get the minimum sqm for each town. Join that with the table to get all the properties with that sqm. Then get the maximum resale value within each of these groups.

```
SELECT t1.town, t1.floor_area_sqm, MAX(t1.resale_value) AS resale_value
FROM flat_prices AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT town, MIN(floor_area_sqm) AS floor_area_sqm
    FROM flat_prices
    GROUP BY town
) AS t2 ON t1.town = t2.town AND t1.floor_area_sqm = t2.floor_area_sqm
GROUP BY t1.town, t1.floor_area_sqm
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qSExBMfjiHSCgsSMS9L8E8/0)

In MySQL 8.0 you can do it in one query with window functions, but I still haven't learned to use them.

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed the error when you indicated about having. I assumed having can derived just from MAX() however, i needed to indicate a number in Having. I was under the illusion that using having could solve without using join. But this help clear alot!

Comment: You can do it in `HAVING` by using a correlated subquery: `HAVING floor_area_sqm = (SELECT MIN(floor_area_sqm) FROM flat_prices t2 WHERE t2.town = t1.town)`

Comment: I tried resulted in only 4 answers. ```SELECT town, floor_area_sqm, resale_price
FROM flat_prices t1
GROUP BY town
HAVING floor_area_sqm = (SELECT MIN(floor_area_sqm) FROM flat_prices t2 WHERE t2.town = t1.town);```

Comment: You need `MAX(resale_price)`

Comment: Actually, that's wrong, because `HAVING` filters after the aggregation. Just do it as in my answer.

Comment: Yup, your answer is correct. Seems this might be the only way by using joins. Just curious if can be done another way. Will probably check. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the elaboration. This is the correct answer. I also wrote one , which prioritizes the highest resale price , then pick the one with the lowest sqm if multiple choices exist. And I find I don't have to list the `resale_value` column in the last group by clause.

Comment: If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled I think you need to list it.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I have the following for the sql_mode : `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: But if I remove the `and resale_value=mx_value`  part for the join condition, an error occurs indicating Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Without that condition, it's not restricted to just one value from the group, so you get that error.

Comment: Yes. But what really beats me is without listing the resale_value in the group by, and having ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY value in the sql_mode, how could the query run without throwing the error `Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause`

Comment: MySQL checks whether the non-aggregated columns are uniquely determined from the grouped columns. When you use that column in the `ON` condition, it's uniquely determined, so it doesn't need to be in `group by`.

Comment: That explains it. I'm all grateful for your enlightenment. Thanks a million, Sir Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

This one goes for the highest resale price , then choose the one with the lowest sqm if multiple choices exist.

```
select t1.town ,min(floor_area_sqm) mi_sqm,resale_value from flat_prices t1 
join
    (select town,max(resale_value) mx_value from flat_prices group by town) t2
on t1.town=t2.town and resale_value=mx_value
group by town
;
```